# Eloquent outside Laravel

Tags: php, oop, eloquent

For the first time i'm trying to create a project from beginning for test Eloquent outside Laravel.

Folder Structure

```
-> orm
    ->app
        -> models
            ->customer.php
            ->database.php
        -> controllers
    ->vendor
->index.php
```

composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "illuminate/database": "^5.4"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Controllers\\": "app/controllers/",
        "Models\\": "app/models/" 
        }
    }
}
```

app/models/database.php

```
<?php
namespace Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class Database{
    function __construct() {
        $capsule = new Capsule;

        $capsule->addConnection(array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'user',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => ''
        ));

        $capsule->bootEloquent();
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    }
}
```

app/models/customer.php

```
namespace Models;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model {

}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Models\Database;

new Database();

$customer = Customer::find(1);
$customer->address1 = "His address, 45";
$customer->name = "my customer";

$customer->save();

echo $customer->name;
```

executing this (record id = 1 exists) it gives me this error:
Fatal error: Class 'Customer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\index.php on line 8

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you watched the [Laracasts lesson](https://laracasts.com/lessons/how-to-use-eloquent-outside-of-laravel) on this?

Comment: After your comment i saw that video, but i only found the solution adding use Models/Customer;

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner and I don't know why it worked, but for me putting the following code on "composer.json" made it run(note that in version is the latest version of those dependencies, so you probably need to run composer require...(and each of them)).

```
    "require": {
    "illuminate/database": "^10.0",
    "illuminate/container": "^10.0",
    "illuminate/contracts": "^10.0",
    "illuminate/support": "^10.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.66"

},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).